# Is calling a superinterface's default method possible?

Tags: java, interface, super, default-method

Say I have two classes, `A` and `B`:

```
class A
{
    void method()
    {
        System.out.println("a.method");
    }
}
```

```
class B extends A
{
    @Override
    void method()
    {
        System.out.println("b.method");
    }
}
```

After instantiating `B` as `b`, I can call `B`'s method like `b.method()`. I can also make `B`'s method call `A`'s method with `super.method()`. But what if `A` is an interface:

```
interface A
{
    default void method()
    {
        System.out.println("a.method");
    }
}
```

```
class B implements A
{
    @Override
    void method()
    {
        System.out.println("b.method");
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make `B`'s method call `A`'s method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use

```
A.super.method();
```

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) states

> If the form is **`TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier`**, then:
>
> It is a compile-time error if `TypeName` denotes neither a class nor an interface.
>
> If `TypeName` denote a class, C, then the class to search is the superclass of C.
>
> It is a compile-time error if C is not a lexically enclosing type
>   declaration of the current class, or if C is the class Object.
>
> Let `T` be the type declaration immediately enclosing the method
>   invocation. It is a compile-time error if `T` is the class Object.
>
> **Otherwise, `TypeName` denotes the interface to be searched, `I`.**